# Customizing the Clarity theme for version 1.0

Tags: vmware-clarity

Prior to version 1.0 beta, I customized the clarity theme and it looks perfect. However, when I upgraded to the current beta version 1.0, I noticed that some data grid component parts like cell headers and pagination controls are a bit off.
Below shows how I generate SCSS themes for light & dark mode using clarity's built-in SCSS files. The SCSS imports below doesn't have any custom theme so it should generate clarity's built-in theme. My goal here's to have a pre-generated css that I can load dynamically when switching themes. Again, the issue here is that the data grid footer and cell headers are off. Is there something I'm missing?

Light:

```
@import "node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/bootstrap/bootstrap";    
@import 'node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/dependencies.clarity';
@import 'node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/components.clarity';
```

Dark:

```
@import "node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/bootstrap/bootstrap";    
@import 'node_modules/@clr/ui/src/dark-theme';
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just solved this issue. I need to prefix the generated css using postcss cli. Now, it looks neat.

Comment: Out of curiosity what browser are you testing in?

Comment: I'm mainly testing it in latest Chrome but I also had that issue in Edge and Mozilla. It was then fixed when I auto-vendor-prefixed the compiled css. I still have to try it in minified version though. Btw, I compiled it in an angular library project (the one that is inside the projects folder in an angular workspace).

Comment: Oh yes, we do process with postcss to setup all those prefixes but if you try to build yourself those won't get handled automatically.